# Move payment methods in Woocommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, checkout

I have to move the payment methods in the checkout page of  a Woocommerce website above the order review, but I don't know how. The problem is, that I tried using the following code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 ); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

But also the "Terms and Conditions" text and the "Place order" button are moving with that. I need to have the payment options, then the order review, and in the end the "Terms and Conditions" text and the "Place order" button.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838884/change-payment-methods-location-before-order-details-table-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 17):

#### Original WC Hook

```php
// includes/wc-template-hooks.php:214
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

#### Your Hook

This will be in your theme or plugin.

```php
// make sure the priority value is correct, running after the default priority.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
```

Your hook should run after WC has loaded; so that you can remove it.

```php
function theme_wc_setup() {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_wc_setup' );
```

EDIT: Thanks all, didn't know this is still actively searched. Vote up to help other devs!

Comment: hooked it to `woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review` in my case as no `woocommerce_after_order_notes` was in template

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to do something similar - to move the Ts&Cs above the payment methods.  But there's something odd going on with Woo checkout Ts&Cs. There appears to be a hook for the privacy text and a hook for terms text, but no hook for the actual tickbox, so you can use hooks for the first two, but not the actual tickbox which is annoying. Seems like the entire "woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper" div - that contains all three, should be hookable.

Anyway, I found it easier with jQuery to move my div - and as I was not able to find an easy way to move the terms div - instead, I moved the Payment Div - (which is what you've asked for, so I'm sharing here in case it's useful).

Add this snippet to functions file.  Amend insertBefore to whichever div you want to move it.  In my example, it's going after the terms and conditions. Tested and working.

```
function stacko_woomove_paymentmethods() { 
    if (is_checkout() ) { ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($) {
              $(document).ready(function(){
$('.wc_payment_methods.payment_methods.methods').detach().insertBefore('button#place_order');
$('.wc_payment_methods.payment_methods.methods').before('<h3 class="note">Select Payment</h3>');
    });
  });
</script>
<? }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'stacko_woomove_paymentmethods');
```

Answer (score -2):

Template override is necessary (not possible editing functions.php only).

One possible way to achieve what you want is:

1. Copy payment.php from woocommerce plugin folder to your_child _theme/woocommerce/checkout/ folder.
2. Open the newly created payment.php file, and add a custom hook just before the line `<div class="form-row place-order">`. For example:

   `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_and_proceed' ); ?>`
3. In your child theme's functions.php, add the code below to unhook woocommerce_order_review action from it's original place, and hook it to the newly created hook:

   `remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );`

   `add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_and_proceed', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );`

Comment: Hello Mikel, event after so many months, is it possible if you can to explain your steps above ? Can you make a detailed description on how that works ? I am also new to wordpress and I don't get easily the hooks/actions