# Change checkout order review section in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I have successfully moved the payment methods section before he review order table: [Change payment methods location before order details table in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838884/change-payment-methods-location-before-order-details-table-in-woocommerce/51845863#51845863).

I would like to add an `<h3>` headline  ("Your order") and a `<p>` paragraph ("I have accepte the terms…") in checkout page, **just above** the review order table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will replace in your existing code the following block:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'reordering_checkout_order_review', 1 );
function reordering_checkout_order_review(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review','woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'custom_checkout_payment', 8 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'custom_checkout_place_order', 20 );
}
```

By this code block (keeping the 2 other functions):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'reordering_checkout_order_review', 1 );
function reordering_checkout_order_review(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review','woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'custom_checkout_payment', 8 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'after_custom_checkout_payment', 9 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'custom_checkout_place_order', 20 );
}

function after_custom_checkout_payment() {
    ?>
    <div id="before-order-table" class="woocommerce-checkout-custom-text">
        <h3><?php _e("Your order", "woocommerce"); ?></h3>
        <p><?php _e("I have accepted the terms and bla bla bla", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]