# Change checkout table order review section in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I followed our friend's solution [Change checkout order review section in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848171/change-checkout-order-review-section-in-woocommerce) and now I need to edit the css only from the information table after payment, in which file would I be able to change the css of this table?
i want it to align right at the top of the page, I've already tried using the selector itself and the id with:

```
display: flex;
align-items: right;
```

and it has no effect

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding the CSS with `display: flex!important;` "important".

Where have you written the CSS code sofar?

Comment: This answer seems more like a comment. If you post vague answers to poor questions, you can lose reputation when people downvote answers that are not definitive.