# Woocommerce checkout: Move woocommerce-checkout-payment to bottom of the first large-7 column just below the woocommerce-billing-fields

Tags: woocommerce

On the woocommerce checkout page:
Can I move the woocommerce-checkout-payment part (last part on the checkout page) to the bottom of the first large-7 column just below the woocommerce-billing-fields.

Yes, you caught me: I want to recreate the shopify checkout page in some kind of way.

In the form-checkout.php there are two columns in the form-checkout.php:

```
    <div class="row pt-0 <?php echo esc_attr( $row_classes ); ?>">
    <div class="large-7 col  <?php echo esc_attr( $main_classes ); ?>">
```

and

```
    <div class="large-5 col">
```

Can I achieve this by altering the form-checkout.php?

There is a solution here but it is six years old and a lot of things changed since then.
I would be happy to edit the template itself (cloned to my child theme folder, of course)
[Change payment methods location before order details table in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838884/change-payment-methods-location-before-order-details-table-in-woocommerce?noredirect=1&lq=1)